# Snowflake bulk upload error. unexpected '-'

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to bulk upload a file in Snowflake via my file from Google Cloud.

Below is the error message I'm getting

> SQL Statement error: 42000 (1003)
> SQL compilation error:
> syntax error line 14 at position 32 unexpected '-'.
> syntax error line 14 at position 32 unexpected '-'.
> syntax error line 14 at position 37 unexpected '<EOF>'.

crunch-base is the name of the bucket on GCP.

Comment: Hard to tell what the issue is without seeing the SQL that is being executed.

Comment: File format, copy into statement, sample data,  etc, all required

Comment: and stage definition if you are using one

Comment: Welcome at stack**overflow**. Does the error message (now) look *exactly* like what you're getting - `SQL compilation error` on a line of its own, `line 14 at position 32` reported twice? Why explain `crunch-base`?